# modulus operand in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some code that executes every 10,000 iterations. 
I am using the modulus like `if i % 10000 == 0` then do something. You see the 'something' below (`pg_conn.exec function`) in the code but anyway my question is, that pg_conn.exec needs to be done for the last remaining iterations as well that may not actually be evenly devisable by 10,000. How can I do that? My program executed the `pg_conn.exec` function 5 times hence the variable `i` was equal to 50000. The program calls for a total of 56,000 iterations. How do I take care of the remaining 6,000 iterations?

```
conn.query("select * from my_tbl") do |r|
    sql += "('#{r[:main_id]}', '#{r[:rep_dt]}', '#{r[:create_dt]}')"

    if i % 10000 == 0
    pg_conn.exec(sql + ';') # important statement that executes only every 10000
    end
end
```

Comment: just call it again after the block

Comment: `sql` is just a string, right? Then use `sql << "..."` instead of `sql += "..."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just call the code again outside the block. remember to reset your sql string inside the if block :)

UPDATE: added a check so that the last call to `pg_conn.exec` will only be executed if something changed in the sql.

```
base_sql_statement = ... # base sql statement here
sql = base_sql_statement

conn.query("select * from my_tbl") do |r|
  sql += "('#{r[:main_id]}', '#{r[:rep_dt]}', '#{r[:create_dt]}')"

  if i % 10000 == 0
    pg_conn.exec(sql + ';') # important statement that executes only every 10000
    sql = base_sql_statement
  end
end

if sql != base_sql_statement
  pg_conn.exec(sql + ';')
end
```

Comment: This would execute the `pg_conn.exec` 6 times for `i=50000`.

Comment: hmm then just check for sql's value before you execute it. i'm going to update my code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your code block where `i` is coming from, but you'll need to know what the maximum value for `i` is going to be to be able to recognize whether you're in the remainder group or not.  Assuming you can get your hands on max_i, replace your current `if` with `if i % 10000 == 0 || i > ((max_i / 10000) * 10000)` to leverage integer arithmetic.